# nginx multiple PHP files in try_files instruction

Tags: php, nginx, vhosts

Good morning,
I want to make the same nginx vhost that can work with different php applications (symfony and Thelia). 
My problem is with the **try_files** instruction. In symfony the try_files must target **app.php** but in Thelia it must target **index.php**.
So I wanted to modify the try_files statement as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.tld;

    root /var/www/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config|index|index_dev)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php_alias:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Php is no longer interpreted. So how can I register multiple php files in the try_files statement?

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using the given regex for the PHP files instead of the standard `location ~ \.php(/|$)` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV Yes, I need this specific configuration but I don't see the relation with try_files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `try_files` directive can only have one *default URI* which is the last element and comes after all of the *file* elements. The problem you are encountering is that the *file* elements cause the request to be processed within the current `location`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

You could use a named `location` to handle the optional default URI, for example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    if (-f $document_root/app.php ) {
        rewrite ^ /app.php last;
    }
    rewrite ^ /index.php last;
}
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.